# is it possible to write more than one character instead of one character on my emulator using gesture in android?

Tags: android, android-gesture

i am writing one app using gesture,in my emulator screen i can write only one character if i write second character the first character disappeared. suppose i want to write one word my emulator screen 'book' on my emulator screen.

Comment: Please explain your question a brief